# EOFError in Line 6. How can I resolve it?

Tags: python, algorithm, eof

I am getting an error in this snippet of code:

**CODE:**

```
import sys

sys.stdin = open("shuffle.in", 'r')
sys.stdout = open("shuffle.out", 'w')

n = int(input())
shuffle = list(map(int, input().strip().split()))
ids = list(map(int, input().strip().split()))
past_order = [0] * n

for _ in range(3):
    for i in range(n):
        past_order[i] = ids[shuffle[i] - 1]
    
for i in past_order:
    print(i)
```

**ERROR:**
line 6, in 
`n = int(input())`
EOFError: EOF when reading a line

**Shuffle.in Contains:**

```
shuffle.in isnt empty. it has this:

5
1 3 4 5 2
1234567 2222222 3333333 4444444 5555555
```

Thanks!

Comment: shuffle.in isnt empty

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're trying to use `input()` instead of `read()` or `readlines()`? You know `input()` prompts for user input?

Comment: no, not any particular reason, but I have specified that all input and output will go in files.

Comment: For every line in the file you'd have to call `input()` again. Also, does `import os; os.getcwd()` display where you expect "shuffle.in" to be located?

Comment: it gives me the file path i am working in

Comment: That's a bit unexpected. Are you running this on Google Colab or something else in the cloud?

Comment: i just edited my comment, i tried it again, and it gave me the file path i am working in.

Comment: Your revised code works without error for me. You might try reading "shuffle.in" as a string and inspecting for stray newlines or some other oddities in the file.

Comment: I resolved the issue. Thanks!

Comment: please close the question or remove when solved..